# how setResultTransformer method works in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I wanted to know how does **setResultTransformer** method works in hibernate internally?

is it a better way loop over all the elements of the **list of Object[]** which is returned after calling **list()** method , cast them and manually assign them in DTO. Does it reduce the time taken in execution or it is same.

Does it loop over all the elements after fetching it from database ?

sorry for asking so many questions but they all are related. Thank in advance